# How do I use the Playstation 2 multitap?

Tags: ps2

I recently bought a new Playstation 2 slim and a new multitap to allow me to play with more than two players at once, but am unsure how to get it to work as it did not come with instructions or box or anything.

I want to get it to work so that I can play Star Wars Battlefront with my friends, however when I plug in a controller, it does not even register or anything.

Answer (score 2):

I had some trouble with my multitap at first, but I've had it working for some time now.

If you have already verified that your model multitap and your model PlayStation will talk to each other then you're ready to follow the steps below (modified from an eHow article).  If you haven't verified this, or aren't sure how, open a new question with the model number of your Playstation and information about the multitap you have, preferably with picture.

1
Find a game that will support three or more players.

2
Turn off your PlayStation.

3
Place the game in the CD tray.

4
Plug the multitap into the first player slot of your PlayStation.

5
If needed, plug the controller or a 2nd multitap into the second player slot of the PlayStation.

6
Plug up to four controllers into the multitap.

7
Turn on your PlayStation.

8
Set up the game with the controller in the first player slot.

9
Play on.

Answer (score 1):

Also, not sure if this helps, but I've been told that the multitap flat out doesnt work with playstation slim. This is unconfirmed, but again, its what I've been told.

Comment: The original PS2 (phat) multitap cannot be plugged into the newer slim models (as the multitap connects to the memory card slot and because the controller slot and memory card slot on the slim is shallower). However there are third-party adapters that allow the original multitaps to be used.

Answer (score -1):

Which port the multitap goes into varies somewhat from game to game. Normally, (unless the game supports more than 4 players) it goes in slot 1, with all controllers plugged into it.

Edit: Make sure you game supports more than 2 players.

Comment: If a game supports 8 Players, you can even put a multitap in both ports!

Comment: I already tried this multiple times, but to no avail. My PS2 did not even register that there were controllers in the multitap.

Comment: I think I know why. SW:BF 1 and 2 only supports 2 players offline, more for online and land but you need multiple systems and copies of the game. see: http://www.co-optimus.com/game/2144/playstation-2/star-wars-battlefront.html and http://www.co-optimus.com/game/2145/playstation-2/star-wars-battlefront-ii.html

Answer (score -1):

You have to blow in the end of the multitap and player slot you insert it into, I also had the same problem with my ps2 slim, bu also Star wars battlefront 1 & 2 are both only 2 player games.